# Вертикальное меню

Tags: jquery, php, html

Пытаюсь сделать вертикальное меню с JQUERY по аналогии с аккордионом
Кусок из ПХП кода

```
 $menu="";
    ob_start();
    function menu($id){
    dbConnect();
    $zapros=mysql_query("select * from menu_admin where id_id={$id}") or die (mysql_error());
    while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($zapros)){
    echo "<li><a href='admin/index.php?&id={$row['id']}'>{$row['name']}</a><ul>";
    menu ($row['id']);
    echo "</ul></li>";
    }
    }
    menu(0);
    $menu=ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
```

Кусок из шаблона ТПЛ

```
 <div class="menu">
    {menu}
    </div>
```

Собственно сам аккордион-меню

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.content dd').hide();
        $('.content  dt').click(function(){
        $(this).next().toggle(100);
        return false;
        });
        $('content dd').next().hide();
         $('.content dt').click(function(){ 
         $('.content dt').each(function(){ $(this).next().hide();
      });
      $(this).next().toggle(100); 
      return false;
       });
        $('content dd').next().hide();
        });
```

Пыталься заменять теги всяко разно - не помогло. Может в чем то другом изюминка?

Comment: расскажите подробно, что вы пытаетесь сделать.

Answer (score 1):

Зачем формировать меню в php, это должно делаться в шаблоне. Сейчас у вас 3 не связанных куска кода, которые не могут работать правильно. В Jquery вы обращаетесь к несуществующим классам.